# Android - MalformedURLException on HTTP request

Tags: android, http, ksoap2, malformedurlexception

I'm fairly okay at programming so this is a wierd one for me...

I'm attempting to pull a value from Mantis Bug Tracker to display on my Android app. To do this I'm accessing Mantis' SOAP interface using the kSOAP2 library.

The error i get is a MalformedURLException with these details

> Protocol not found: /api/soap/mantisconnect.php

The URL is built from a user entered URI with a String attached onto the end:

```
String fullUrl = HOST + "/api/soap/mantisconnect.php/mc_version?wsdl"; 
trans.call(fullUrl, soapEnvelope);
```

HOST is passed in successfully, i have seen this through debugging variables and fullUrl equates to:

```
http://192.168.1.98/mantis/api/soap/mantisconnect.php/mc_version?wsdl
```

This is copied right out of the debug view for the HOST variable in Eclipse.

The point at which the program errors out is at trans.call(); where trans is an HTTPTransportSE object provided in the kSOAP2 libraries. The URL that is defined in trans is (oddly?):

> /api/soap/mantisconnect.php

So to me this problem appears to lie in a parse issue within the HttpTransportSE object, for which source can be found [here](http://ksoap2.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ksoap2/trunk/ksoap2/ksoap2/src_j2se/org/ksoap2/transport/HttpTransportSE.java?revision=148&view=markup) extending transport.java (i can't put a link as it thinks im spamming but you can find it in that SVN).

Normally by this point, i've spotted the problem and never have to hit the submit button but i'm having real issues with this =(. All help welcome & necessary!

Comment: what's answer u got for solution?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried it without the `HOST` variable and just hard code the URL?

Comment: Just attempted now, good thinking but unfortunately it hasn't resolved the problem =\

Comment: Apologies, problem solved, you were correct in thinking the URL was not being set correctly. Before calling trans.call(x,y); you set up the HTTPTransportSE object with the URL i hadn't been doing this at runtime hence no input to it!

Comment: Would it possible to get the stack trace?

Comment: Too big to post in, however i'll throw up whatever you need [here](http://jackthorpe.me.uk/androidtrace.html). Probably best to browse source on that though.

Comment: It's okay as long as you have fixed the issue. You would need edit the original post for the stack trace. Please make sure you accept this answer it helped you.